# Firebase v9 modular - How do you use onSnapshot to return an observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to use Firebase v9 modular version and I'm confused as to how to use onSnapshot. I'm trying to execute a query and listen to the documents.

Following is my code :

```
    getUsersBoards(){

    return this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(
      filter((user)=> !!user),
      mergeMap(async (user) => {
        const collectionRef = collection(this.firestore, 'boards');

        const q = query(collectionRef, where("owner", "==", user.uid));

        return onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot)=>{
          return querySnapshot;
        });

      })
    );
    
  }
```

I was expecting an `Observable<board[]>`, but I'm getting a `Observable<unsubscribe>`

Is there a way so that I can do the following ?

```
boards$: Observable<board[]>;

...
this.boards$ = getUsersBoards();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `Observable<unsubscribe>` because, according to the Firebase docs, `onSnapshot` returns "[a]n unsubscribe function that can be called to cancel the snapshot listener."

Try converting the snapshot to an observable first, before returning. For example:

```js
        new Observable(observer => {
          return onSnapshot(reference,
            (snapshot => observer.next(snapshot.data())),
            (error => observer.error(error.message))
          );
        });
```

Comment: In this example how should the unsubscribe be handled ?